# Node.js transform stream hangs until end readstream

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, stream, nodejs-stream

At the moment I'm implementing a pipeline with streams for CSV files to write its lines to a db with a certain model. I started out with writing everything to stdout. That let to unexpected behavior quickly, when I attached my custom (Transform) product map stream.

At first I started out using only the fs readstream, piped that to the csv transformer (based on the npm package csv-streamify) and wrote to process.stdout. Everything was flowing like normal.

But then I connected my custom transformer and there it starts to act weird. Because as soon as I apply any operation (JSON.parse, typeof chunk) in to the chunk in the transform, the data will not flow directly to stdout but, as it appears, only when the readstream is done.

Does anybody know why this occurs?

My pipeline:

```
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'file1.csv');

//From NPM module: csv-streamify
const csvTransformer = csv({objectMode: false, columns: true});
const mapper = new CsvMapper();
const productMapStream = ProductMapStream.create(mapper);
const writeStream = ProductWriteStream.create(this.connectionPool);

  fs.createReadStream(filePath)
    .pipe(csvTransformer)
    .pipe(csvProductMapStream)
    .pipe(process.stdout)
    .on('finish', () => resolve('Ok'))
```

My custom transform stream:

```
export class ProductMapStream {

  static create(mapper: ProductMappable) {
    return new Transform({
      transform(chunk: any, enc, callback) {
        try {
          const chunkAsString = chunk.toString('utf8');
          // This already prevents continuous flowing
          const newString = '' + (typeof chunkAsString);
          this.push(newString);
          callback(null);
        } catch (e) {
          callback(e);
        }
      }
    }).once('error', console.log)
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

After some experimentation based on the comments of @PatrickDillon I've found out that this problem only occurs when it's run inside a Docker container. I've tried different node versions based on Docker node images. I started out with node:8.12.0-alpine and I've also tried node:10.11.0-jessie but no difference in behavior unfortunately. Does anybody know of special behavior of when using Docker with fs or streams or anything that might seem related?

Comment: Are you saying the stdout is displayed all at once? I'm unable to replicate, and wrapped the callback in the custom transform with a setTimeout (`setTimeout(() => {
            callback(null);
          }, 100);`  to verify data piped to stdout could be throttled.

Comment: Yes. It outputs nothing for a while (I assume it is until the readstream is finished) and then it all displays at once. When I return chunk.toString('utf8').toUpperCase() it also flows like normal, everything upper cased as expected...

Comment: My example is of course an isolated snippet to illustrate my issue. @PatrickDillon your comment surprised me so I've also created a new isolated set-up to see what happens and indeed, it works when I implement this behavior isolated, without Typescript. I'm baffled but this gives at least gives me new handles to explore the problem.

Comment: Possibly something in the TypeScript compilation is resulting in code that buffers the data? Depending on your Node version, have you tried forwarding the transformed data in the callback instead of this.push? `callback(null, newString)`

Comment: Yes, I've also tried that. The thing I didn't point out is that I'm using a docker container to run the process. The isolated experiment was running without Docker. Now that I've ported the code to run inside the docker container it shows exactly the same undesired behavior. This was information that I wouldn't have thought to be relevant. I started out with node:alpine v8.9. Now I'm running on node:jessie v10.11.0. No difference in behavior. Could it be related to the workings of fs with Docker?

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem when executing streams with and without docker. Without docker, the stream emits "finish" after the stream is complete ~ 2 minutes. Inside of docker, the stream emits "finish" immediately, although I can see the job continutes to access the database for the full 2 minutes.